# Trying to parse all information from Tempbooking model to Booking model if the admin changes is_active to 'true' in the tempbooking django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-database

This is the model:

class Booking(models.Model):

```
booker = models.CharField(max_length=50)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.EmailField()
discount_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, 
blank=True)
guest_no = models.PositiveIntegerField()
arrival_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, 
auto_created=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True,blank=True)
departure_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'booking'
    managed = True
    verbose_name = 'Booking'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Bookings'
```

class Tempbooking(models.Model):

```
booker = models.CharField(max_length=50)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.EmailField()
discount_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, 
blank=True)
guest_no = models.PositiveIntegerField()
arrival_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, 
auto_created=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True,blank=True)
departure_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, 
blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name

class Meta:
    db_table = ''
    managed = True
    verbose_name = 'Tempbooking'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Tempbookings'
```

This is the form:

class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
  discount_code = forms.CharField(required=False)
is_active = forms.HiddenInput()
class Meta:
    model = Tempbooking
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'booker': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Your username'}),
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Your First Name'}),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Your Last Name'}),
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Your Email'}),
        'guest_no': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'arrival_date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'date'}),
        'departure_date': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'date'}),
        'discount_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'If our discounted product'})
    }
```

This is the view:
def booking(request):

```
form = BookingForm()
form2 = TempbookingForm()
if request.method=='POST':
    form = BookingForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() or form2.is_valid:
        form2 = TempbookingForm(form)
        form2.save()
        return redirect('booking')

context = {
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'booking.html', context)
```

I'm trying to make it so that if the admin logs into the admin page and changes is_valid to 'True', all the information in the Tempbooking model would be saved into the booking model...Please how do i go about it?

Comment: It might be more efficient if you just make a single booking model with additional Boolean Field, IsActive which will be false by default. And as admin approves it, that field gets updated.

Comment: Yeah, just thought of it and the way you suggested works better, would be easier for me to just use a filter to divide the ones that is_active is true from the one that is_active is false